# I installed a plug in to eclipse but no getting in menu

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, green-uml

I installed a plug in in eclipse helios for green uml generation from http://green.sourceforge.net/builds.html this site. installation completed successfully. I restarted the eclipse.I followed the steps given in http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp310/Eclipse/GreenUML/  site. But I am not getting  rightclick->new->others-> green uml diagram
I didn't get any green uml diagram. I installed soyatec euml .Same problem there also. Can any one suggest what I should do. Thanks

Comment: Do you see the plugin as installed when you go under Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details ?

Comment: ya....... I was trying to install it as user, so I got this problem . Once I installed it as admin its working fine.